# Removing points from geom_bar legend ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

This is my data.

```
Mod <- as.factor(c(rep("GLM",5),rep("MLP",5),rep("RF",5),rep("SVML",5),rep("SVMR",5)))
Manifold <- as.factor(rep(c("LLE","Iso","PCA","MDS","kPCA"),5))
ROC <- runif(25,0,1)
Sens <- runif(25,0,1)
Spec <- runif(25,0,1)
df <- data.frame("Mod"= Mod, "Manifold"= Manifold, "ROC" = ROC, "Sens" = sens, "Spec" = spec)
```

And I am making this graph

```
resul3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Mod, y = ROC, fill= Manifold)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
ylab("ROC & Specificity") +
xlab("Classifiers") +
theme_bw() +
ggtitle("Classifiers' ROC per Feature Extraction Plasma") + 
geom_point(aes(y=Spec), color = "black", position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
scale_fill_manual(name = "Feature \nExtraction", values = c("#FFEFCA", 
"#EDA16A" ,"#C83741", "#6C283D", "#62BF94"))
```

[first graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHB0H.png)

And what I want is another legend with tittle "Specificity" and a single black point. I dont want the point to be inside the Manifolds legend.

[Something like this but without the points inside the manifold squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bql46.png)

Comment: Put the `color` into the `aes()` of `geom_point` to create a second legend.

Comment: I guess he wanted to get rid of the dots completely within the legend.

Comment: He said he wants `another legend with tittle (sic) "Specificity" and a single black point`. So your answer is partly right, but you'd need to add the second legend to the `aes` of `geom_point`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the `geom_point` line, adding a `scale_color_manual` and using the override as seen in @drmariod's answer will result in this plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Mod, y = ROC, fill= Manifold)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  ylab("ROC & Specificity") +
  xlab("Classifiers") +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Classifiers' ROC per Feature Extraction Plasma") + 
  geom_point(aes(y=Spec, color = "Specificity"), position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Feature \nExtraction", values = c("#FFEFCA", 
                                                              "#EDA16A" ,"#C83741", "#6C283D", "#62BF94")) + 
  scale_color_manual(name = NULL, values = c("Specificity" = "black")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite the aesthetics for shape and set it to `NA` like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Mod, y = ROC, fill= Manifold)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  ylab("ROC & Specificity") +
  xlab("Classifiers") +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Classifiers' ROC per Feature Extraction Plasma") + 
  geom_point(aes(y=Spec), color = "black", position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Feature \nExtraction", values = c("#FFEFCA", 
  "#EDA16A" ,"#C83741", "#6C283D", "#62BF94")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)))
```